# Invert colors on each layer of an animated GIF

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, batch-processing

I have a rather involved black and white animated GIF generated by code for which I want to invert the colors for every frame of the animation sequence. How can I do this? If I select multiple layers in Photoshop, the *invert* command becomes no longer available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply add an *Invert Fill Layer,* and this will invert all layers below it.

[image]

Comment: It’s now *Layer → New Adjustment Layer → Invert.*

Comment: You can still add it from the Layers panel as shown in the screenshot -- but yes you could also go through the menus at the top as you describe.